# json parsing not working on device on Corona

Tags: storage, coronasdk

Json parsing is not working on devices while works perfect on simulator, that scene could not be open where I read or write some data.
I have made a class for Json parsing
Here it is,

```
module(..., package.seeall)

local json=require ("json")


function saveTable(t,filename)
    local path = system.pathForFile(filename, system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local file = io.open(path,"w")
    if file then
        local contents = json.encode(t)
        file:write(contents)
        io.close(file)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function loadTable(filename)
    local path = system.pathForFile(filename, system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local contents = ""
    local myTable = {}
    local file = io.open(path,"r")
    if file then
        local contents = file:read("*a")
        myTable = json.decode(contents)
        io.close(file)
        return myTable
    end
    return nil
end
```

I actually want an alternative of NSUserDefaults on Corona.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I got it, I used to loadTable first, without saving table, so it would be a problem, never call loadTable before save table :)

Comment: yea :)
but now I am facing this problem, please consider it and help me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360009/sound-is-not-working-properly-in-corona-sdk