# Sound is not working properly in Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

I have a problem when I gave channel number to a sound. When I did not give channel number to a sound then it plays perfect and it also plays when I play that sound, so it stops the previous sound and play new sound.
But when I play that sound with a specific channel, then it would not plays repeatedly, it use to wait for completion of previously playing sound, then it plays the new sound

For example,

I have put a sound to play when ball strike with walls, but when ball strikes again to wall, sound is not playing until previous sound not play completely.
Any Help?

Comment: Can you post some code?  It's hard to know what's going on if we can't see how you're trying to play your sounds.  Also show how you are loading them and any other audio.* api calls.

Comment: "sound is not playing until previous sound not play completely."-- what does this sentence really mean? Post your code will help us to figure out what you really want do.